# Yii:: How to use CDbCriteria as cache dependency

Tags: php, caching, yii

When we define the cache dependency with CDbCacheDependency, we have to provide a SQL as the dependency. When we are using CDbCriteria, its not possible to provide the sql, as the sql is built via critera with proper paramters token.

Is there any way we can use the CDbCriteria as the cache dependency ? Is it right to ask such thing ? as I'm only interested in the sql being built by the CDbCriteria, other I would have to build sql manually and I think that is not right.

Thank you

Comment: Can you show a sample criteria?

Comment: there is no direct way, but you can use CDbCriteria indirectly as i've mentioned in answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of Yii 1.1.13 I'm afraid you will **have** to use an SQL statement, and there is no direct way of using `CDbCriteria`.

However *there is an **indirect** way* of using `CDbCriteria`, but ultimately you will have to use it to generate an SQL command, which you'll pass as your dependency. This technique uses [`CDbCommandBuilder`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCommandBuilder) and its methods.

Sample (see comments for understanding):

```php
$criteria=new CDbCriteria;
// ... replace with code to set up your criteria ...
// ...
// first create commandBuilder instance
$commandBuilder = new CDbCommandBuilder(Yii::app()->db->schema);
// then create command using criteria
$command = $commandBuilder->createFindCommand('table_name', $criteria);
// then get sql statement text
$sql = $command->text;
// then set your dependency
$dependency = new CDbCacheDependency($sql);
// if you have params in the criteria, set the params for dependency
$dependency->params = $criteria->params;

// now your dependency is usable
```

---

In the above I have used `createFindCommand`, there are other methods like `createCountCommand` in `CDbCommandBuilder`, use one which generates the sql statement that you have to run.

---

Alternatively you could have used [Query Builder](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.query-builder), but of course there wouldn't be any `CDbCriteria` there.

Comment: Thanks @bool.dev, although it requires a version upgrade but it worked. Thanks.

Comment: No problem. but version upgrade? you mean 1.1.13? i actually meant that this is the case till 1.1.13 (and i don't know what will happen in future versions), so even if you are using an older version, it should work as long as the methods are available, but of course i can't be sure. I did test this on 1.1.10 and above though, but i think all the classes used have been there since 1.0 so it should work on older versions too. however `params` of `CDbCacheDependency` has been there since 1.1.6, so you could say that __this will work for all versions >= 1.1.6__ .

Comment: oh ok, actually I thought it will be used only in 1.1.13, thats why i downloaded it. I will make sure it works in 1.1.11.